# class io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver cannot be cast to class io.qualityplus.flutter.driver.AppiumFlutterDriver

Tags: appium, flutterdriver

I want to cast Appium Driver To
`AppiumFlutterDriver.`
I implemented this methodes:

```
 import io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.ios.IOSDriver;
import io.qualityplus.flutter.driver.AppiumFlutterDriver
public static AppiumFlutterDriver getAppiumFlutterDriver(AppiumDriver driver) {
        return getTargetObject(driver);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings({"unchecked"})
    private static <T> T getTargetObject(Object proxy) {
        try {
            while ((AopUtils.isCglibProxy(proxy))) {
                return getTargetObject(((Advised) proxy).getTargetSource().getTarget());
            }
            return (T) proxy;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new UnproxyDriverException();
        }
    }
```

I get the error:

```
Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: class io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver cannot be cast to class io.qualityplus.flutter.driver.AppiumFlutterDriver (io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver and io.qualityplus.flutter.driver.AppiumFlutterDriver are in unnamed module of loader 'app')
```

I expect that the casting is happing to FlutterDriver and AndroidDriver